# Using Helper to create unique id and pass to partials in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am using panini for my front end development and generate html dynamically.

So I am wondering are we able to pass helper function to partials to generate unique ID for each partials?

In my helper I have this function

UniqueID.js

```
function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

// Example file src/helpers/bold.js
module.exports = function(options) {
    var uuid = guid();
    return uuid;
}
```

for generate different unique ID

and in the pages folder I wish to pass the helper function to partials

`{{> component id={{UniqueID}} }}`

so that in the pages level I can have a different unique id for each component call, but in partials level will share the same id value.

```
<style>

    .component-{{id}} {
        styling here
    }
</style>

<div class="component-{{id}}">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit quidem accusantium cumque. Soluta eligendi possimus voluptas dolores, porro ullam facilis atque consectetur eius iste, repellendus ex esse hic ipsum ducimus.
</div>
```

but the panini showing me this error
Expecting 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'OPEN' etc.

is that some limitation in handlebars or the way I think is wrong?

Comment: `{{> component id={{UniqueID}} }}` should be written as `{{> component id=(UniqueID) }}` (assuming UniqueID is a helper) or `{{> component id=UniqueID }}` if it's a parameter.

Comment: ops, is working! Thanks!